# Cannot edit delete button of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell and I want to edit the delete button of the cell.
I've tried to use the next code but the if statement never goes true.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
    {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
        {
            // the next if statement never goes true
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"])
            {
                //... edit the button
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What change are you trying to make? And you do realize that there is more than one level of subviews in a table view cell, correct?

Comment: I want to add 2 custom buttons one above the other in the side of every cell.
Yes in know there is more than one subviews level. I also tried some code which run through all the subviews of the subviews but got same result.